# Delete an entity with many to many relationship in EF Core

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

I have two tables `Products` and `Categories`:

```
[Table("Categories")]
public class CategoryEntity : BaseEntity 
{
    public string? Title { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ProductEntity>? Products { get; set; }
}

public class ProductEntity : BaseEntity 
{
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Subtitle { get; set; }
    
    public IEnumerable<CategoryEntity>? Categories { get; set; }
}
```

I did not add `ProductCategory` table because EF Core creates it automatically in the database.

Now I want to delete a `Product` or a `Category`, but I get an error about existing relationship. How can I prevent this and delete the entity and the relationships?

```
await _dbContext.Set<CategoryEntity>()
                .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                .ExecuteDeleteAsync();
```

here is stack trace:

System.InvalidOperationException: The association between entity types 'CategoryEntity' and 'CategoryEntityProductEntity (Dictionary<string, object>)' has been severed, but the relationship is either marked as required or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, configure the relationship to use cascade deletes. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the key values.

Comment: Have you tried using EF Core as an *ORM*? Removing the root entity will remove the related owned entities as well, provided cascading is configured. `ExecuteDeleteAsync` exists as a surrogate for non-ORM operations.

Comment: I tried your code in the post and there was no problem. Can you share another section or provide more explanations

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi no promblem? how...
there is no other thing here.  this is it. all the code I wrote.

Comment: There was no problem and the information was deleted. It is probably related to your framework